# How can I change the background color in a specific row of jQuery jTable?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-jtable

```
rowInserted: function (event, data) {
   if (data.record) {
       if (condition1 == condition2) {
          $('#div1').find(".jtable tbody tr").css("background", "#F5ECCE");
       }
   }
}
```

the above code could be changing all row color, can i specify row number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [:eq() selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) like,

```
rowInserted: function (event, data) {
   if (data.record) {
       if (condition1 == condition2) {
          $('#div1').find(".jtable tbody tr:eq(1)").css("background", "#F5ECCE");
          // changing first row background color
       }
   }
}
```

**Updated** you can set **index dynamically** like

```
$('#div1').find(".jtable tbody tr:eq("+index+")").css("background", "#F5ECCE");
```

Comment: is it possible to get row dynamically?

Comment: where i get `index`(row number) value?

Comment: @user2119324 `index` and `row number(starting from 0)` are same here.

Comment: If you want to get the current index you should write : var rowCount = $('.jtable tr').length; and then in your index -> your write rowCount-1 ( in the eq selector )

Answer (score 4):

Rohan Kumar and raevilman's answer works fine. But the code can be shortened and runs faster by using data.row

```
rowInserted: function (event, data) {
   if (data.record) {
       if (condition1 == condition2) {
          data.row.css("background", "#F5ECCE");
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example below will change the 4th rows background color

```
var $rows = $('#div1').find(".jtable tbody tr");
var ROWNUMBER = 3;
$($rows[ROWNUMBER]).css("background", "#F5ECCE");
```

Alternatively you can use the pseudo class selector :eq() to select the number you want only, this also uses 0 based indexing.

```
var ROWNUMBER = 3;
var $row = $('#div1').find(".jtable tbody tr:eq(" + ROWNUMBER + ")");    
$row.css("background", "#F5ECCE");
```

Comment: is it possible to get row dynamically?

Comment: @user2119324 You can set the ROWNUMBER to whatever you like, alternatively if you're appending a row to the end you could use $('#div1').find('.jtable tbody tr').last().css()

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var rowNumber = 1;
$('#div1').find(".jtable tbody tr").eq(rowNumber).css("background", "#F5ECCE");
```

Comment: is it possible to get row number dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

To get row id dynamically
Use like following

```
rowInserted : function(event, data) 
        {
           var index = data['row'][0]['rowIndex'];
           $('#npoDiv').find(".jtable tbody tr:eq("+index+")").css("background", "green");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building up on **raevilman**'s answer which was not working for me due to a little detail:
with **rowIndex** I get indices starting at **1**, but the CSS path below has the first row indexed at **0**, hence the -1 when i assign the value to the variable **index**.

```
        rowInserted: function(event, data) {
            if (data.record.value>100){
                var index = data['row'][0]['rowIndex']-1;
                console.log('decorating row with index: '+index);
                $('#div1').find(".jtable tbody tr:eq("+index+")").css({"background":"red"});

            }
        }
```

This correctly highlights in red the rows whose "value" field is greater than 100.

Answer (score 0):

To do this after the table has been loaded, and if you know the key of the row, you can use the following:

```
    $("tr[data-record-key=" + rowKey + "]").addClass(rowClass);
```